Firebase Cloud Storage limiting access by file, can't not list files in storage
In Firebase Cloud Storage I've created the below rules, where  will be the signed in customers UID
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    
    match /{fileID} {
      allow read: if fileID == 'design_x.pdf' && "accesscode_123" in
      firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/customers/<UID>).data.purchased
      allow read: if fileID == 'design.y.pdf' && "accesscode_567" in
      firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/customers/<UID>).data.purchased
    }

The above rules work to allow or prevent access to the files.
But when I then try to access Cloud Storage from the web to list all files a customer has access to, there is a permission error
    import { getStorage, ref, list, listAll } from "firebase/storage"

    const storage = getStorage(app, "gs://<storage URL>")

    const storageRef = ref(storage)
    const files = await list(storageRef);

    console.log(files)

The above code works if I give access to all files, but if I try to limit permissions per file then I can't list which files the customer has access to? Any way to do this via the Cloud Storage rules?

Per the documentation, "security rules are not filters". If you try to access (or query) a file you do not have permission to, the entire query will fail. In your scenario, one of the best solutions I can think of off the top of my head would be to store the list of documents in a Firestore document or collection at something like /users/<UID>/purchasedFiles where you can query over that collection and then request the files directly as needed.

I don't think I've ever answered this question in the context of Storage rules, so do you feel like posting it as an answer @samthecodingman?
